# How to handle or create the model class for the data receiving from kafka which is emitted from neo4j streams?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, neo4j, confluent-platform

i am trying to understand the receiving model from the kafka which is emitted from neo4j streams to one kafka topic.

Actually that data is looing like below.

```
{
  "meta": {
    "timestamp": 1608725179199,
    "username": "neo4j",
    "txId": 16443,
    "txEventId": 0,
    "txEventsCount": 1,
    "operation": "created",
    "source": {
      "hostname": "9945"
    }
  },
  "payload": {
    "id": "1000",
    "before": null,
    "after": {
      "properties": {
        "name": "sdfdf"
      },
      "labels": [
        "aaq"
      ]
    },
    "type": "node"
  },
  "schema": {
    "properties": {
      "name": "String"
    },
    "constraints": []
  }
}
```

so to consume this type of complex structured data in springboot from kafka we need to create nested model?

i mean nearly 4 classes nested each other?

From my understanding i am trying to create the below classes.

```
meta (**This is 1st class**)
    "operation": "created",

payload(**This is 2ndclass which is nested inside the Meta**)
    id
    before
    after(**it is 3rd class which is nested to payload**)

        properties(**it is 4th class which is nested with in after**)
            these data only we needed to store
        labels
    type
```

Actually i didn't faced thee kind of nested issue before so don't have idea to procees?

so is the above method is right or any other possiblities are there?

Have to consume the data from kafka topic which is emitted by neo4j streams is the ultimate goal?

Language : Java

Framework: Springboot

Comment: You could create a POJO. Yes, they'd be nested. Or just use JSONObject

Comment: Thank you so much @OneCricketer ,i am also doing the same .   By adding nested POJO's it is working for me.it took nearly 5-6 POJO class to form one consumer model class. so only looking for any alternative solutions

Comment: Well, for properties, for example, you could use a Hashmap because that's probably not a strictly defined object. Otherwise, you might be able to pull some dependency that Neo4j would use themselves that actually includes those model classes